# Concatenate string and list to create a list of paths

Tags: python

I need to read a bunch of csv files in pyspark in databricks.

`spark.read.option("header", True).format("csv").load('path/2021', 'path/2020')`

Is it possible to make it dynamic with some variables like this?

`years_to_query = ['2020', '2021']`

`path = 'path'`

I'm trying to concatenate but I'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: Concatenation should work easily here. I don't know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't use string concatenation to join file-system path components, use `os.path.join()`, which isn't OS-specific.

Comment: You don't need `zip()` or `Itertools.repeat()` here as @azelcer suggested — use `load(*(os.path.join(path, year) for year in years_to_query))` instead which makes use of a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to create the arguments.

Comment: You could also use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module and do it like this: `load(*((Path(path)/year) for year in years_to_query))`.